# Python Scraping exits with sleep and counts wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to run the following program every 10 Minutes, but after the 10 Minutes the Program exits with "Code=0". I also want to add for each row except the writeheader a ID, this is working but on the other entries it counts all rows.

How do i let this Program run every 10 Minutes?
How do i only count the row except the writeheader row?

I'm pretty new to Python, most likely this a not a mayor Issue.

```
import time
import smtplib
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
from datetime import datetime
import os.path


URL = 'https://stockx.com/de-de/supreme-jostens-world-famous-champion-ring-gold'

INTERVAL = 10

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
search_for_class = soup.find_all(
    'div', class_="sale-value")
print(search_for_class)

x = str(soup.find('div', class_="sale-value"))
preis = str(re.sub("<.*?>", "", x))

print(preis)

datum = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
uhrzeit = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print(datum)
print(uhrzeit)

file_exists = os.path.isfile("test_file.csv")
if not file_exists:
    open('test_file.csv', 'w+')

with open('test_file.csv', 'r+') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['ID', 'Datum', 'Uhrzeit', 'Preis']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
    entry = len(csv_file.readlines()) + 1

    # csv_file.write("\n")
    if not file_exists:
        writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({
        'ID': entry,
        'Datum': datum,
        'Uhrzeit': uhrzeit,
        'Preis': preis
    })
    csv_file.close()

time.sleep(INTERVAL * 60)
```

Comment: put a `while True:` loop around everything starting from `page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it run every 10 minutes, put a loop around everything that should run repeatedly.

To make the `ID` count correct, you can write the header line in the `if not file_exists:` block when you first create the file. That way the `entry` count will always include the header line.

As a simplification, you can open the file once before the loop. Then increment `entry` each time through the loop. Use `csv_file.flush()` to make sure the new line is written to the file.

```
import time
import smtplib
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
from datetime import datetime
import os.path

URL = 'https://stockx.com/de-de/supreme-jostens-world-famous-champion-ring-gold'
INTERVAL = 10

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36'}

file_exists = os.path.isfile("test_file.csv")
if not file_exists:
    with open('test_file.csv', 'w+') as f:
        f.write('ID,Datum,Uhrzeit,Preis\n')

with open('test_file.csv', 'r+') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['ID', 'Datum', 'Uhrzeit', 'Preis']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
    entry = len(csv_file.readlines())

    while True:
        page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
        search_for_class = soup.find_all(
            'div', class_="sale-value")
        print(search_for_class)

        x = str(soup.find('div', class_="sale-value"))
        preis = str(re.sub("<.*?>", "", x))

        print(preis)

        datum = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        uhrzeit = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        print(datum)
        print(uhrzeit)

        writer.writerow({
            'ID': entry,
            'Datum': datum,
            'Uhrzeit': uhrzeit,
            'Preis': preis
        })
        csv_file.flush()
        entry += 1

        time.sleep(INTERVAL * 60)
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar for your help. That was easier then i thought to fix.